# SQLite Cursor Loads Different size of data everytime I read data from my memory

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, cursor, android-mediaplayer

In SQLite(Android), Cursor Loads Different size of data every time I read data from my memory. **First, I am accessing data to initialize my RecyclerView to display a list of song and then again accessing data to assign it to my music player service. But RecyclerView shows more songs than music player Service can play. whenever I play some songs from the end of the list it gives me an error saying**

"java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 83, Size: 81"
number varies everytime I restart the app.

https://github.com/KaustubhMemane/BeatBox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kmema/android/beatbox/MainActivity.java

Comment: If you edit your question to show that you have read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I might consider looking into the issue.

Comment: @MikeT thanks, I  solved it .. I was reading a data from memory by Async operation and before I could get my data, I was calling Async operation again from another location to get me a data ...  that was messing up with my overall functionality.